# Send Given Amount of Tokens From Script to Wallet

Tags: plutus

Which TxConstraints i o method should I use to create a transaction where the script pays a specified amount to the wallet? The `mustSpendScriptOutput` is the only one I can find that sends tokens from the script to the wallet, but it sends all the tokens at a utxo. I am looking to send a specified amount, and the change is returned to the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UTxOs can only be consumed completely which means you will have to create a new output at the script address that receives the change that shall stay with the script which can be done via `mustPayToTheScript <datum> <value>`.

Comment: When I added that to the constraints the transaction failed. Is there a way I can post my code in multiple lines in a comment?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207842/how-to-easily-indent-multi-line-code

Comment: I'm getting a ConstraintResolutionError TxOutRefNotFound during the ledgerTx line of code
````
utxos <- utxosAt $ scriptAddress payValidator
let orefs = fst <$> Map.toList utxos
     change = _ciTxOutValue (snd (L.head (Map.toList utxos))) - (Ada.lovelaceValueOf bet)
     lookups = Constraints.typedValidatorLookups typedPayToScriptValidator
     tx = Constraints.mustSpendScriptOutput (last orefs) unitRedeemer <> Constraints.mustPayToTheScript bet change
ledgerTx <- submitTxConstraintsWith lookups tx
void $ awaitTxConfirmed $ getCardanoTxId ledgerTx
````

Comment: Looks like your TxOutRef is invalid and does not exist. Check your orefs

Comment: I needed to add `Constraints.unspentOutputs utxos` and `Constraints.typedValidatorLookups myValidator` to my lookups variable. Thanks for the help, I appreciate it.